# Is it possible to block users who are using IP masquerading services?

Tags: php, nginx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to find and how to block blacklisted IPs and proxies?](https://serverfault.com/questions/289785/where-to-find-and-how-to-block-blacklisted-ips-and-proxies)

There are certain programs that change the IP a user appears to be coming from.
I would like to know if there is a way to block these users, and only allow them to visit my website using their real IP.

Comment: I really couldn't make sense of your original question, so I've tried to translate it into something closer to standard English. If I totally mangled your meaning please let me know :-)

Answer (score 5):

Since you're talking about nginx you're talking about TCP-based protocols. There is no practical way to "change the ip address" and have two-way communication, which is necessary for TCP-based protocols to work.

Something like [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/) routes traffic through a network of machines to disguise the original source IP address of the traffic. Your server would see the source IP address as being the last node in the TOR network (called the "exit node") that the traffic was routed through. There's no practical way for your nginx server to keep track of all the possible TOR exit nodes for blocking traffic from those nodes (that list changes every day) and no practical way to recover the original source IP address.

Comment: sad, knowing That Prohibit someone will return with fake ip

Comment: @Anonimo - That's the Internet. If you want to positively identify users and block them they're you're pretty much stuck implementing some type of authentication mechanism. IP addresses don't correspond to people.